# Neo4jConfig, no default constructor found. Spring REST Hateoas problems

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, neo4j

Been fighting with this for a while, cannot get past this Exception no matter what combination of spring/neo versions I use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Full stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/SDM7fsBA

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'organizationRepository': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'neo4jTemplate' while setting bean property 'neo4jTemplate'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'io.trips.rest.WebAppInitializer$Neo4jConfig': 
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Could not instantiate bean class [io.trips.rest.WebAppInitializer$Neo4jConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d147012]: 
No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: io.trips.rest.WebAppInitializer$Neo4jConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d147012.<init>()
```

WebAppInitializer.java:

```
//@Import({JpaConfig.class, MongoConfig.class})
//@ImportResource("classpath:META-INF/spring/security-config.xml")
@Configuration
@Import({Neo4jConfig.class})
public static class AppConfig {

    @Bean(initMethod = "loadData")
    public Neo4jLoader dataLoader() {
        return new Neo4jLoader();
    }

}

//public class Neo4jRepositoryConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "io.trips.rest.neo4j")
@Configuration
public class Neo4jConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    static final String DB_PATH = "target/neo4j-test-db";

    @Bean  //(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public EmbeddedGraphDatabase graphDatabaseService() throws IOException {
        FileUtils.deleteRecursively(new File(DB_PATH));
        return new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(DB_PATH);
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate() throws IOException {
        return new Neo4jTemplate(graphDatabaseService());
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jMappingContext neo4jMappingContext() {
        return new Neo4jMappingContext();
    }

    @Bean
    public JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean transactionManager() throws Exception {
        return new JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean(graphDatabaseService());
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jExceptionTranslator exceptionTranslator() {
        return new Neo4jExceptionTranslator();
    }

    /**
    @Bean(initMethod = "loadData")
    public Neo4jLoader neo4jLoader() {
        return new Neo4jLoader();
    }
    */
}}
```

Organization.java (a node)

```
@NodeEntity
public class Organization {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    //@Indexed(unique = true, indexName = "Geo")
    String name;
}
```

Organization.repository

```
package io.trips.rest.neo4j;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;
public interface OrganizationRepository extends GraphRepository<Organization> {
}
```

Pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.0.M1</spring.security.version>
    <springdata-jpa.version>1.3.1.RELEASE</springdata-jpa.version>
    <springdata-neo4j.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</springdata-neo4j.version>
    <springdata-rest-webmvc.version>1.1.0.M1</springdata-rest-webmvc.version>
    <jackson.version>2.1.2</jackson.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.2</slf4j.version>
</properties>
```

Here is a full stacktrace:

Comment: Remove the neo4jTemplate() method in Neo4jConfig. It will instantiate correctly because its already defined in Neo4jConfiguration. What happens now?

Comment: Thanks. But I still get the exact same error.   ` Error creating bean with name 'io.trips.rest.WebAppInitializer$Neo4jConfig': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [io.trips.rest.WebAppInitializer$Neo4jConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a73cba7a]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: io.trips.rest.WebAppInitializer$Neo4jConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a73cba7a.<init>()`

Comment: This may be useful information - the neo5j-test-db directory is not being created in the target path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to move the class Neo4jConfig out of the WebAppInitializer class.